# How to have Maven excluded source packages to be reflected in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using maven-compiler-plugin I specified three packages to be ignored from source. However, after importing the project into IntelliJ, those folders are treated as source packages normally, and this happens after every POM reorganization. Needless to say, I have to exclude them manually after every POM change.

I know there was some maven-idea plugin, but I see it has been retired. I use IDEA 13.

How to make IntelliJ IDEA to support packages exclusion based on Maven?

Relevant pom excerpt:

```
<plugin>  
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>2.3.2</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>test/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>unused/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>my/test/package/unused/**/*</exclude>
    <excludes>
<configuration>
</plugin>
```

Works fine for Maven build (classes from excluded packages do not compile).

Comment: Can you post your maven file to show what exactly you mean?

Comment: Why are you excluding files? Does not make sense.